# How to use FIND_IN_SET in codeigniter query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$array = array('classesID' => 6);
$this->db->select()->from($this->_table_name)->where($array)->order_by($this->_order_by);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

I need to get the rows where the classesID is 6. Some rows contain 6,5,4.
  so i need to use FIND_IN_SET query to retrive where the classesID is 6.

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the value in the 'classesID' column might be "4,5,6" ?

Answer (score 6):

[image: 'Action history table with studentsIds as comma separated values]

I need to get the rows which has student id '4488' and message id '1418'

```
$id = 1418;
$student_id = 4488;
    this->db->select('id, action_status, updated_on, student_ids');
    $this->db->where('message_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('find_in_set("'.$student_id.'", student_ids) <> 0');
    $this->db->from('actions_history');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

It will return a query like

```
SELECT id, action_status, updated_on, student_ids FROM actions_history  WHERE message_id = '1418' AND find_in_set("4488", student_ids) <>0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$array = array('classesID' => '5,6,7');
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from($this->_table_name);
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('classesID',".$array['classesID'].")",null,false);
$this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: the syntax is wrong it should be FIND_IN_SET(' ".$array['classesID']." ' , 'classesID'), first the string to find and then in second argument the column to look into , isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query like this.

```
return $this->db->where('classesID' , '6')->order_by('column_name','desc')->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

if Need any help comment

Comment: Thank you bro. I used this query $this->db->select()->from(student)->where('FIND_IN_SET(6, classesID)');

Comment: But i don't know how to pass id from controller to model?

Answer (score 0):

For those who're looking for model (CI v4.x) based solution,

```
$modal->where("FIND_IN_SET('<string to find>', '<column name>')", null, false)->findAll();
```

In your case,

```
$modal->where("FIND_IN_SET('".$array['classesID']."', 'classesID')", null, false)->findAll();
```