# Query where_in comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a 'list_table' table looks like:

```
id :  list 
1  :  1,2,44,5    
2  :  4,3,5,2,56,66
```

Is it possible to check if '44' is in List column in mysql database?
I'm using codeigniter and my code looks like:

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from("list_table");
$this->db->where("find_in_set('44', 'list')");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

I also tried with WHERE_IN but didn't get correct result.

This is what query I get when I enable_profile:

```
SELECT *
FROM `poslovi`
LEFT JOIN `firme` ON `firme`.`f_id` = `poslovi`.`po_firma_id`
LEFT JOIN `kategorije` ON `kategorije`.`k_id` = `poslovi`.`po_category`
WHERE `po_date_istek` > '2022-03-21 10:37:25'
AND   (`po_naziv_oglasa` LIKE '%Radnik u ćevabdžinici%' ESCAPE '!' OR  `f_name` 
LIKE '%Radnik u ćevabdžinici%' ESCAPE '!')
AND find_in_set("61", po_category) <> 0
AND `po_status` = '1'
ORDER BY `po_date_istek` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This is what I have in my database:
[image]

Just to mention, if I remove 'find_in_set' I get correct result so the rest of the query is good as I noticed

Comment: well, the main problem here is [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) e.a. What is if you have in your table values like 44, 444 and 4444, how often would 44 be found, erroneously most likely. Try to restructure your database.

Comment: Actually, I tried to put these values in another table but database is kind big and I have few join tables as well, I have issue with memory, website crash

Comment: ^ this is most likely due to a non optimal database setup, missing indexes, incorrect order of executing joins and many more. *memory issue, website crash*: that is a very vast description of what you have running is going wrong.

Comment: maybe you need json format in DB? look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951528/how-to-insert-data-in-json-format-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [a screenshot you posted of your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPinf.png), its possible to see that you include a space after each comma.

The value of `po_category` is `2, 7, 61`, not `2,7,61`—and `find_in_set` does not ignore those spaces!

You've noticed that `find_in_set` works when you search for the first entry, this is because that does not have a leading space;  `7` and  `61` do.

`find_in_set(" 61", po_category)` would match, in this case, but then it wouldn't match if it **is** the first entry. While you could do `(find_in_set("61", po_category) <> 0 || find_in_set(" 61", po_category)) <> 0` to support both cases, that is unnecessarily slow and taxing. Just save your data without spaces. Or, better yet, not as a comma separated list.

*In [nbk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542981/316310) there's a link that explains why doing this is not optimal. One way to save a list of IDs is making a separate table for them and using JOINs. This will be better for performance. Another option that is slightly more complex to implement, if you are using MySQL 8.0.17 or higher, is to save it as a JSON array & index that array.*

Comment: This was a problem, now it's OK, thanks. On the other way I will consider reorganizing database structure

Answer (score 3):

You need a true or false condition in the WHERE clause, so a comparison

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from("list_table");
$this->db->where("find_in_set('44', 'list') <> 0");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

But it ot recomended to store data this way . Read mor in [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Doesn't work, anyway thanks for advice, I will reconstruct database. Cheers

Comment: i am wondering why this doesn't work there are many example that ot works just fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509723/how-to-use-find-in-set-in-codeigniter-query

Comment: I get the result only if '44' is in the first place in comma sep list

Comment: that is strange run the raw query in workbench or so and try it. FIND_IN_SET works on every position. Maybe a bug in your version

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from the 'list' in the where statement: `$this->db->where("find_in_set('44', list) <> 0");`

Comment: @KobusMyburgh he said it works only if 44 is at the start, so the column is recognized

Comment: I have tested out the code I posted above, with the data he used, and it is working for me as I did it. I also want to refer you to this page: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/. I am not sure it is getting picked up this way, as 44 is literally checked against a string with value 'list'

Answer (score 0):

As nbk said, you need the true/false condition, however, the answer is not working for the OP. You need to remove the single quotes around `list` in that answer:

```
$this->db->where("find_in_set('44', 'list') <> 0");
```

Rewrite the code as below, minus the quotes around `list`:

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from("list_table");
$this->db->where("find_in_set('44', list) <> 0");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

That should solve the issue for you.